# If f is coercive and $\mathrm{epi}(f)$ closed, $\min f(x)$ has at least one solution

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Let $\mathrm{epi}(f)=\{(x,\alpha)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| f(x)\le\alpha\}$

Prove or disprove:

If $f$ is coercive and $\mathrm{epi}(f)$ closed, the problem

$\min f(x), x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

has at least one solution.

If $f$ is coercive, then $\lim_{\|x\| \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\infty$.
But I don't know how this helps me. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

This is the corollary of Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem.

If $f$ is optimized over an unbounded set, then for a coercive function $f$, we can take a bounded interval say $\mathcal{B}$, such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq a \ \forall x \in \mathcal{B}$. Now, we can use the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to prove the existence of at least one infimum.

---

To prove the attainability of the infimum, $f$ has to be lower semi-continuous. If the epigraph of $f$ is closed, then $f$ is lower semi-continuous. A deligant prove can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/468984/177357).

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Glombik for pointing that out. I rectified it.